# JavaScript HTML Loading two scripts

Tags: javascript, html

So I am creating a site for a project at school and am keeping it simple, all I want to do is be able to load two scripts at the same page. I have searched alot and can't find a straight answer. I read that I might have to use the window.onload twice or something along those lines. They work separately but not both, it always uses the second script.

The first script is a sorting script for the table i have on my:

```
      function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
    var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
        tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
        i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
        return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
            * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
    });
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
}

function makeSortable(table) {
    var th = table.tHead, i;
    th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
    if (th) i = th.length;
    else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
    while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
        var dir = 1;
        th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))});
    }(i));
}

function makeAllSortable(parent) {
    parent = parent || document.body;
    var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'), i = t.length;
    while (--i >= 0) makeSortable(t[i]);
}

window.onload = function () {makeAllSortable();};
```

And then there is the second script which is bringing a div when scrolling:

```
window.onload = function() {

  function getScrollTop() {
    if (typeof window.pageYOffset !== 'undefined' ) {
      // Most browsers
      return window.pageYOffset;
    }

    var d = document.documentElement;
    if (d.clientHeight) {
      // IE in standards mode
      return d.scrollTop;
    }

    // IE in quirks mode
    return document.body.scrollTop;
  }

  window.onscroll = function() {
    var box = document.getElementById('box'),
        scroll = getScrollTop();

    if (scroll <= 355) {
      box.style.top = "365px";
    }
    else if (scroll >= 862) {
        box.style.top = "892px";
    }
    else {
      box.style.top = (scroll + 10) + "px";
    }
  };

};
```

My intentions with this is not only to make it look better but if i could learn how to use multiple javascripts if i encounter it again, and i might learn more advanced scripting later, right now I'm looking for a way to get this working, thanks in advance for ANY tips and advice you can give me.

(Dont hesitate with advice around my layout for the question either, I do intend to use this or other forums alot this summer so it can be good if I do it the right way)

Comment: Edwin, how are you using these scripts in the HTMl page, I mean are you giving the path of the scripts in HTML page?

Comment: You can attach only one function by using `window.onload` _property_, the second `onload` overrides the first-one. You can use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to attach multiple listeners, or call the second snippet from the first (just create it as a named function instead of anonymous).

Comment: Mozak, Yes I'm giving the paths straight to the file trough <script>

Comment: Teemu, can you explain and show what you mean by changing it to a named function instead of a anonymous?
I didn't really mention it but I have absolutely 0 experience with JavaScript, I know the basics of programming though so you do not have to explain extremely in-depth, just, quite in-depth since I don't know the syntaxes and such. And if possible explain how I should go about using addEventListener() if I would go for that solution, if you have time of course. I more or less understand what you both are saying, I just don't know how to go about making it, examples would be helpful.

Comment: Usage of `addEventListener` is explained in the linked MDN article. A couple of working answers below seem to do what you need though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AddEventListener is probably a good way to go (as per @Teemu). And put the onload inside script tags seems good too (as per @agmcleod).

As you seem to be starting with javascript etc I would like to propose an other way to organize your code:

```
// make it tableHandler.js
var tableHandler = {
    sortTable: function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
        var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
            tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
            i;
        reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
        tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
            return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
                * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                    .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
                );
        });
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
    },
    makeSortable: function makeSortable(table) {
        var th = table.tHead,
            i;
        th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
        if (th) i = th.length;
        else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
        while (--i >= 0)(function (i) {
            var dir = 1;
            th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                this.sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))
            });
        }(i));
    },
    makeAllSortable: function makeAllSortable(parent) {
        parent = parent || document.body;
        var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'),
            i = t.length;
        while (--i >= 0) this.makeSortable(t[i]);
    }
};

// make it scrollHandler.js
var scrollHandler = {
    getScrollTop: function getScrollTop() {
        if (typeof window.pageYOffset !== 'undefined') {
            // Most browsers
            return window.pageYOffset;
        }
        var d = document.documentElement;
        if (d.clientHeight) {
            // IE in standards mode
            return d.scrollTop;
        }
        // IE in quirks mode
        return document.body.scrollTop;
    },
    onscroll: function () {
        var box = document.getElementById('box'),
            scroll = this.getScrollTop();
        if (scroll <= 355) {
            box.style.top = "365px";
        } else if (scroll >= 862) {
            box.style.top = "892px";
        } else {
            box.style.top = (scroll + 10) + "px";
        }
    }
};

// make it a third script or put inside script tags
window.onload = function () {
    tableHandler.makeAllSortable();
    scrollHandler.getScrollTop();
}
window.onscroll = function () {
    scrollHandler.onscroll();
}
```

Here we have two objects, one that knows about tables and one that knows about scrolling. When the window object "tells" them the load event (or the scroll event) happened they do what they're supposed to do.

I was gonna make a fiddle to see it working, but there was no HTML. Anyway, I started it: http://jsfiddle.net/slacktracer/LA5p7/2/

This is just one of many ways to do it. Not the most sophisticated, but it presents some nice concepts.

But remember, you'll have to load your files in the right order because when the window.onload event happens if the tableHandler (or scrollHandler) variable doesn't exist you'll get an `Uncaught ReferenceError:` for one of them of both. ;)

Do something like this:

```
<script src="/scrollHandler.js"></script>
<script src="/tableHandler.js"></script>
<script src="/theOneWithTheWindowEvents.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, you more or less did it for me right? This is what I was trying before, adding them to the same script running them both but i never got it to work, now I see why more or less.

Id appriciate though(For better understanding) if you tell me what it does to put the functions inside of the var tableHandler and varScrollhandler.

Comment: So i just used the code you did put it in files like you've instructed in it but I get two Uncaught ReferenceErrors from both the script tableHandler and the first script that initates the others. Uncaught ReferenceError: makeSortable not defined. and in the script which initates it: Uncaught ReferenceError: scrollHandler not defined. Any idea why?

Comment: @EdwinW. It's (most likely) because you have to load tableHandler.js and scrollHandler.js before the third script! I'll update my answer.

Comment: @EdwinW. Also, putting the functions inside tableHandler is turning these functions into methods of an object. An object is an element with particular responsibilities. Sometimes it's a good idea to encapsulate some of your logic inside these objects. Or a great idea. (Do you know OOP?)
This `function () {}` is a anonymous (or unnamed) function and this `function iHaveAName() {}` is a named function. I can try to help if you have more questions. And there are a lot of great resources online, of course. But sometimes it's hard to find the good stuff when we're just beginning.

Comment: @EdwinW. Hey, I just saw your profile. I know a little JavaScript and would be willing to help. =) I'm good with dumb questions too. I don't skype, but I do hangout: https://plus.google.com/101685121473345418343/posts
Feel free to get in touch! Thanks for saying I'm awesome! =P

Comment: I did put the initiating script as the last, so, I have no clue, i can send you my head if thats something you might want that to know, and the three scripts as i put them up

Comment: One of the errors was because of a semicolon. The other one was for lack `this` when calling other methods from a object. I don't if you know what it means though. Do you? A great place to learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create
Anyway, I edited the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `addEventListener` as Teemu suggesed is a good option. Another is you can just have the window.onload in your html page, and call the functions in order:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    makeAllSortable();

    var box = document.getElementById('box'),
    scroll = getScrollTop();

    if (scroll <= 355) {
      box.style.top = "365px";
    }
    else if (scroll >= 862) {
      box.style.top = "892px";
    }
    else {
      box.style.top = (scroll + 10) + "px";
    }
  }
</script>
```